# Drupal 7 :: Configure Master admin under Drupal multi domain website

Tags: multi-sites

I want to configure Master admin under Drupal multi domain website so that admin does not need to switch the login between multiple websites.

For example, if I have 3 websites under single Drupal setup:

www.red.com

www.blue.com

www.green.com

Then I should be able to open red.com admin panel and should have the option to switch from red.com to blue.com admin without logout from red.com admin panel.